# Parsing elements with namespace etc. in XML

Tags: xml, haskell, xml-conduit

This question is about how to parse xml content with `xmlns` attributes etc. I wrote code to parse it which works. I will appreciate pointers on whether it can be done better.

I have an XML file `test.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
<SomeResponse xmlns="https://testsomestuff.org/API/WS/">
 <SomeResult>
&lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
        &lt;title&gt;My &lt;b&gt;Title&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Foo bar baz&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
 </SomeResult>
</SomeResponse>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I wrote the code to parse the "SomeResult" content using `xml-conduit`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Prelude hiding (readFile)
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder (toLazyText)
import Data.Text.Lazy (fromStrict)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    doc <- readFile def "test.xml"
    let cursor = fromDocument doc
        res = fromStrict $ T.concat $ child cursor >>= laxElement "Body" >>= child >>= laxElement "SomeResponse" >>= child >>= laxElement "SomeResult" >>= descendant >>= content
        pres = parseText_ def res
        cursor2 = fromDocument pres
        res2 = child cursor2 >>= element "head" >>= child >>= element "title" >>= descendant >>= content
    print $ res2
```

Output in `ghci`: parses correctly:

```
*Main> main
["My ","Title"]
```

Is `laxElement` approach to locate the `SomeResult` content good way to do it? If there is a better way, I will very much appreciate pointers on this.

Also, I need to do http encoding in reverse direction (when building a request for the response above) where the inner body is escaped (like under `SomeResult` in `text.xml`). Is that something that is taken care of by default when building request using `Text.XML`, or do I have to convert the inner body to escaped http explicitly by using something like [html-entities](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/html-entities) ?

Answer (score 1):

Together with `xml-conduit`, I would suggest the use of a tiny 'lens' package such as [xml-html-conduit-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-html-conduit-lens) or `xml-lens` (both are quite similar but I have chosen the first after a quick browse at the source). Namespace is supported (see [this issue](https://github.com/supki/xml-html-conduit-lens/issues/4))

You can look at [one of my experimental project](https://github.com/PierreR/vCloudApi/) if you need a more concrete example. From that project, here is a traversal to get the information of a specific machine from the VCloud API:

```
fetchVM :: AsXmlDocument t => Text -> Traversal' t Element
fetchVM n = xml...ovfNode "VirtualSystem".attributed (ix (nsName ovfNS "id").only n)
```

You can then combine traversals [as such](https://github.com/PierreR/vCloudApi/blob/master/src/vcloud.hs#L46):

```
vmId = raw ^. responseBody . fetchVM vmName . fetchVmId.text
```

Look at how `ovhNode` or `nsName` is defined to see how I handle namespace.

Here is another interesting article on the subject:
https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/chad/snippets/random-code-snippets/xml-conduit-lens

Another tip is to stick with 'xml-conduit' (at least for now). Some have suggested `taggy` as a replacement but unfortunately it is currently not in an active development cycle (see https://github.com/alpmestan/taggy/issues/14)

I hope it helps.